# Dynamic database field value (HTML & Realtime Firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a following data structure in firbase real time database:

```
-Post
  --key
    ---name: name1
    ---post: article1
    ---comment: some comment
  --key2
    ---name: name2
    ---post: article1
    ---comment: some comment2
  --key3
    ---name: name3
    ---post: article2
    ---comment: some comment3
```

I have comment template (web page) which stores the comment in firebase. I am including that template multiple times on a single page under each post using php include command. But I want to store the post value dynamically (like article 1 or article 2 etc.). How should I achieve that?